# MongoDB: How to find nth highest salary from collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find the nth highest salary in a mongodb from  Employees collection.
also would be really helpful if someone could gimme an idea of applying joins in mongodb.

Answer (score 15):

This should work

```
db.Employees.find({}).sort({"Emp salary":-1}).limit(1) //for first highest salary

db.Employees.find({}).sort({"Emp salary":-1}).skip(1).limit(1) // for second highest salary
```

Similarly you can do `db.Employees.find({}).sort({"Emp salary":-1}).skip(nthVarible - 1).limit(1)`.

Comment: @user4408375 What if first two employees have the same salary. In case of second highest salary.

Comment: @Aabid I have added one answer for that. Although I used two-step process but may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835860/3373597

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
    db.salary.find({}).sort({s:-1}).skip(1).limit(1);
```

For your second requirement - MongoDB is noSQL DB, not a transnational DB. It does not support joins.

Comment: db.salary.find({}).sort(s:-1).skip(1).limit(1);

Comment: {}  should not be used inside sort("s", -1)

Answer (score 2):

I found a two-step process to do it. it will work in the scenario if there are multiple records with salary same as highest.

**Records I have**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc04b02536dc2e493697b4e"), "name" : "Ankit" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0504a536dc2e493697b50"), "name" : "Ankit", "salary" : 1000, "email" : "a@b.com", "joining_date" : ISODate("2019-04-24T12:02:18.528Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0504a536dc2e493697b51"), "name" : "Priya", "salary" : 1300, "email" : "p@b.com", "joining_date" : ISODate("2019-04-24T12:02:18.528Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0504a536dc2e493697b52"), "name" : "Raj", "salary" : 1200, "email" : "rj@b.com", "joining_date" : ISODate("2019-04-24T12:02:18.528Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0504a536dc2e493697b53"), "name" : "Vishu", "salary" : 1500, "email" : "v@b.com", "joining_date" : ISODate("2019-04-24T12:02:18.528Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0504a536dc2e493697b54"), "name" : "Rahul", "salary" : 2000, "email" : "ra@b.com", "joining_date" : ISODate("2019-04-24T12:02:18.528Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc08b5d536dc2e493697b57"), "name" : "Tushar", "salary" : 2000, "email" : "tu@b.com", "joining_date" : ISODate("2019-04-24T16:14:21.061Z") }
```

**Find distinct salaries and store in a variable**

```
sal = db.employee.distinct("salary").sort()
```

**Output:** `[ 1000, 1200, 1300, 1500, 2000 ]`

You can get the second highest salary from this array itself. Below query will give you the record with that salary

```
db.employee.find({salary:{$lt:sal[sal.length-1]}}).sort({"salary":-1}).limit(1)
```

**Output:**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5cc0504a536dc2e493697b53"), "name" : "Vishu", "salary" : 1500, "email" : "v@b.com", "joining_date" : ISODate("2019-04-24T12:02:18.528Z") }
```

Answer (score 1):

I see this question has been asked in many technical interviews.

- `OBJ = client.my_db.employee_table`
- `OBJ.find({}).sort('salary', -1).limit(1)`
- 1 in the index 1 implies ascending order
- -1 in the index 1 implies descending order.
  As we wanna find the highest salary from the table, we must mention -1.

To find **the nth highest salary** in the table.

- `OBJ.find({}).sort('salary',-1).skip(n-1).limit(1)`

**To eliminate rows, we use OFFSET in Mysql/SQL Likewise we must use skip() in MongoDB**

Answer (score 0):

For first, second maximum salary if having multiple records in Mongodb:

**METHOD I : (If NO multiple records exists)**

`db.details.find({}).sort({"salary":-1}).limit(1)` ==> First Highest Salary

`db.details.find({}).sort({"salary":-1}).skip(1).limit(1)` ==> Second Highest Salary

**METHOD II : (If MULTIPLES records exists)**
***Second Maximum Salary :***

`sal = db.details.distinct("salary").sort()` ==> sal = [1000, 1400, 1500, 1700, 2000]

`db.details.find({salary:{$lt:sal[sal.length-1]}}).sort({"salary":-1}).limit(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
db.sales.aggregate({$group:{_id:'$salary'}},{$sort:{salary:-1}},{$skip: 1},{$limit:1})
```

In $skip value you can use n number to skip n number of rows.