# Finding second highest value from record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

please suggest example for finding second highest value from record in mongodb?

```
   {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$studentName",
                    //course: { $ifNull: [ "$course", "MBA" ] },
                    exam: {$push: "$exam"},
                    course: {$push: "$course"},
                    school: {$push: "$school"},
                    Percentage: {$avg: "$marks"},
                    maximum_mark: {$max: "$marks"},
                    minimum_mark: {$min: "$marks"}
                }


   }
```

Comment: highest value based on which key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How to find nth highest salary from collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822058/mongodb-how-to-find-nth-highest-salary-from-collection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your question description. The max and min of `mark` could be retrieved through `$max` and `$min` operator. To find the second high value of `mark` could be done through `$sort` firstly, then `$push` to an array `all_marks` in `$group` operator, then get the second high value through [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/#exp._S_arrayElemAt),

Given data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dfea65199803954abcd1c4"), "studentName" : "name1", "exam"
: "e1", "course" : "math", "school" : "s1", "marks" : 96 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dfeb50199803954abcd1c5"), "studentName" : "name1", "exam"
: "e2", "course" : "math", "school" : "s1", "marks" : 99 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dfeb72199803954abcd1c6"), "studentName" : "name1", "exam"
: "e1", "course" : "english", "school" : "s1", "marks" : 90 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dff03b199803954abcd1c7"), "studentName" : "name2", "exam"
: "e1", "course" : "math", "school" : "s1", "marks" : 86 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dff04d199803954abcd1c8"), "studentName" : "name2", "exam"
: "e2", "course" : "math", "school" : "s1", "marks" : 90 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56dff317199803954abcd1c9"), "studentName" : "name2", "exam"
: "e2", "course" : "math", "school" : "s1", "marks" : 81 }
```

With aggregation

```
.aggregate([
      {$sort: {studentName: 1, marks: -1}}, 
      {$group: {_id:"$studentName", 
                exam: {$push: '$exam'}, 
                course: {$push: 'course'}, 
                school:{$push: '$school'}, 
                Percentage: {$avg: '$marks'}, 
                max_mark: {$max: '$mark'}, 
                min_mark: {$min: '$mark'},
                all_marks: {$push: '$marks'}
      }}, 
      {$project: {exam: 1, 
                  course: 1, 
                  school: 1, 
                  Percentage: 1, 
                  max_mark: 1, 
                  min_mark: 1, 
                  second_max_mark: {$arrayElemAt: ['$all_marks', 1]}
       }}])
```

Output

```
{ "_id" : "name2", "exam" : [ "e2", "e1", "e2" ], "course" : [ "course", "course
", "course" ], "school" : [ "s1", "s1", "s1" ], "Percentage" : 85.66666666666667
, "max_mark" : null, "min_mark" : null, "second_max_mark" : 86 }
{ "_id" : "name1", "exam" : [ "e2", "e1", "e1" ], "course" : [ "course", "course
", "course" ], "school" : [ "s1", "s1", "s1" ], "Percentage" : 95, "max_mark" :
null, "min_mark" : null, "second_max_mark" : 96 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$sort` for sorting it by whatever you need `$skip` the first result and then `$limit` it to 1 result.

Problem solved.

Comment: What if 2 or more students have same top marks? the second highest remains the same as first right?